# How to install VLC on Puppy Linux?

Tags: vlc-media-player, puppylinux

**Question**

I'm new to Linux, have just installed Puppy Linux and would like to install VLC. How do I install VLC? Can anyone provide a step by step guide?

**Versions**

- [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org): LuPu 5.0.1
- [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc): 1.0.5

**Findings so far**

I checked the paket managers but didn't find VLC in it.

I searched the web but didn't find any articles describing how to install the current VLC version. I found some articles describing how to install VLC 0.8.x but didn't find that helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have Lupu 5.01 working with VLC.

My steps to get it working were:

1. Go [HERE](ftp://distro.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/distributions/puppylinux/pet-packages-lucid/) and download the VLC package. Click on it and it should install fine.
2. Run and test.

Problem solving: if the application won't work from the menu after installing, go [HERE](http://dotpups.de/puppy4/dotpups/Multimedia/mplayer-gui-all-deps-001.pet) and install that package as well.

Hope that works for you - it worked for me with a C-Media sound card and just X11 video.

Answer (score 1):

[Puppy Linux Discussion Forum - How to install VLC Media Player](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=44037&sid=6e154875111ff085bed7d8ab6c24da25)

Or

[VLC 1.0.0rc4 Media player .pet for Puppy](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=43728)

Comment: Thank you, amazing response time. Unfortunately, it's not working. Puppy Pakage Manager displayed: "Error, package ... .pet failed to install." for the 1.0.0RC4 version. The 0.8.6 did install and there is an application icon in the menu "Multimedia", but VLC does not start when I click on it, even after rebooting the system. There is also no error message displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find out why a program fails is to try starting it from the command line (also known as the terminal or console). In the case of VLC, you'd probably just need to type in "vlc" (without the quotes). When the program fails various diagnostic messages will print out in the terminal. This will be your clues as to which libraries or other things the program needs. Do a google search for them and download or compile them yourself. Sometimes this is very simple. Sometimes get caught up in an increasingly complex problem that I like to call "dependency hell". The Puppy forums can often help with this.

Answer (score 1):

There are simple steps that you can use to install VLC on Puppy Linux:

1. download a `.tar.gz` version (not sure which packages from wich distributions are compatible with puppy)
2. using terminal, navigate to your `.tar.gz` file (using commands like `cd` and `ls`)
3. use the command `tgz2pet <filename>.tar.gz` (replace `<filename>` by the name of your file)
4. go to to the folder using your file manager
5. install the pet package
6. try to run it...

If it fails to run, try to download a `.tar.gz` file form another distribution.

I am using puppy 4.2.1.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you directed him to download the version that works on YOUR operating system, and not on Puppy Linux.

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/